# Is it grammatical to use "[verb]-ing an [object] by an [subject]"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, gerund-clauses

> The story is about the stoning an innocent young woman for adultery by a group of radical religious hypocrites.

In the above sentence "radical religious hypocrites" is the subject who did the stoning. Is it correct grammatically use *verb-ing* followed by the subject? Or should it be "radical religious hypocrites' stoning of an innocent young woman"? Normally I would think that the noun following "-ing form by" is the instrument used to do the task (verb), rather than subject, e.g. "Opening the door by a key", "Sending a message by the phone" , and so on . Other examples I am skeptic of whose correctness include "reaching international ranks by hardworking athletes", "Opening new national developmental horizons by aerospace scientists", "importing a new class of SUVs by the government", "Watching porn by a frustrated guy", and so on.

Comment: First up, "a **group** of radical religious hypocrites" would be better. Second up, it's not a grammatical subject, but part of a *prepositional phase* headed by the preposition **by**. The only grammatical subject in your sentence is **the story**, and **stoning** is what is called called "gerund-participle" by some.

Answer (score 2):

> stoning of an innocent young woman for adultery by a group of radical religious hypocrites.

it is a gerund phrase as object of the preposition "about".

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/phrases.htm

Comment: So, is it correct to use it this way?

Comment: yes ,the phrase acts as a noun.

Comment: But OP doesn't use "of".